# Spark ML print model (pipeline)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have dataset which was created from dataframe using VectorAssembler, the dataframe is a transformation of `StringIndexer()` for multiple columns
I trained my model :

```
val assembler = new VectorAssembler().....
val data = assembler.transform(...)
val featureIndexer = new VectorIndexer()
val gbt = new GBTRegressor()
      .setLabelCol("label")
      .setFeaturesCol("indexedFeatures")
      .setMaxIter(10)
val pipeline = new Pipeline()
      .setStages(Array(featureIndexer, gbt))
val model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)
```

When I print my model it would look something like:

```
GBTRegressionModel (uid=gbtr_24b22b08fa90) with 10 trees
  Tree 0 (weight 1.0):
    If (feature 16 <= 0.22222222222222224)
     If (feature 16 <= 0.13333333333333333)
      If (feature 16 <= 0.07142857142857144)
       If (feature 16 <= 0.02222222222222222)....
```

My first problem is that I would expect to see  feature name and not feature index when printing the model, how can I resolve that? 
Another problem is caused because I used `StringIndexer()`, which means I would see the mapping of each value as int and not his string value. How can I print the model with the StringType column instead of the one was transformed with `StringIndexer()`?

Thanks for helpers